# why is there a type parameter IO in Request as in http4s Request[IO]?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, cats-effect, http4s

There's a type parameter `IO` in Request as in `http4s` `Request[IO]`.

Why is it necessary, what do we have as an effect here, when is this effect executed?

Comment: Note that there is a difference between `Request[IO]` and `IO[Request]` the last one represents a program that when evaluated will produce a `Request`, but the first one is just a value of of type `Request[IO]` _(which conceptually is not much different from `List[A]`)_ thus, it is just a type parameter. Now, if you see inside `Request` you will see that most methods return values of type `F[X]` or `Stream[F, X]` so you can see that those are - "effectual"_ and `Request` is just abstract to the concrete effect type you will use.

Answer (score 4):

You should read more about the tagless final pattern in Scala.

Here is the Request class:

```scala
abstract case class Request[F[_]](..., ...) extends Message[F] { .. }
```

`Request` needs based on its definition a type parameter `F[_]`

Request has methods that further constraint `F[_]`. For example:

```scala
  def decode[A](f: A => F[Response[F]])(implicit F: Monad[F], decoder: EntityDecoder[F, A]): F[Response[F]]
```

This implicit `F` function argument means we need a Monad defined for `F[_]` otherwise you can't decode the request.

Request is made generic so you can easily use different `F[_]`.
Besides the cats effect one you could use the Monix task.